# Reading CSV and import column data as an numpy array

Tags: pandas

I have many csv file all contains two column. One is 'Energy' and another is 'Count'. My target is to import those data and keep them as a numpy array separately. Let's say X and Y will be two numpy array where X have all Energy and Y have all count data. But the problem is in my csv file i have a blank row after each data that seems making a lot of trouble. How can I eliminate those lines and save data as an array?

```
Energy Counts
-0.4767   0
-0.4717   0
-0.4667   0
-0.4617   0
-0.4567   0
-0.4517   0

import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np
import os 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


file_path = "path" ###file path


read_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path,"*.csv")) ###get all files

X = [] ##create empty list
Y = [] ##create empty list

for files in read_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(files,header=[0])

    X.append(['Energy'])##store X data
    Y.append(['Counts'])##store y data

X=np.array(X)
Y=np.array(Y)
print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)
plt.plot(X[50],Y[50])
plt.show()
```

Ideally if I can save all data correctly, I suppose to get my plot but as data is not saving correctly, I am not getting any plot.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`skip_blank_lines`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) parameter to `True` and these lines won't be read into the dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv(files, header=[0], skip_blank_lines=True)
```

So your whole program should be something like this (each file has the same column headers in the first line and the columns are separated by spaces):

```
...
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in read_files:
    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(file,  sep='\s+', skip_blank_lines=True))

df.plot(x='Energy', y='Counts')
df.show()

# save both columns in one file
df.to_csv('myXYFile.csv', index=False)  
# or two files with one column each
df.Energy.to_csv('myXFile.csv', index=False)
df.Counts.to_csv('myYFile.csv', index=False)
```

---

**TEST PROGRAM**

```
import pandas as pd
import io

input1="""Energy Counts
-0.4767   0
-0.4717   0
-0.4667   0
-0.4617   0
-0.4567   0
-0.4517   0
"""
input2="""Energy Counts
-0.4767   0

-0.4717   0
"""

df = pd.DataFrame()
for input in (input1,input2):
    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(input), sep='\s+', skip_blank_lines=True))

print(df)
```

**TEST OUTPUT:**

```
   Energy  Counts
0 -0.4767       0
1 -0.4717       0
2 -0.4667       0
3 -0.4617       0
4 -0.4567       0
5 -0.4517       0
0 -0.4767       0
1 -0.4717       0
```

Comment: I am not getting any values. df.heads() giving me NaN. an shape of X and Y is (178,1) while I am expecting (178,4092)

Comment: Do all your csv files have the column headers Energy and Count in their fist line?  And why do you think it should be 4092 columns?

Comment: yes all files contain same header as it is an outcome from a machine. Each file contain 4092 energy data and 4092 count data

Comment: is there anyway that i can share one file with you for better understanding?

Comment: Your so-called csv (=comma separated values) file doesn't have commas as separators, but spaces, therefore you'll have to specify them explicitely. Also, I forgot the assignment in the loop, my bad. Now it should work (tested with your sample data)

Comment: Now I get error while appending data in df . the error is "pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 3
"

Comment: Also sublime text showing th '\s+' in different color(purple)...It is same like when i define my path I have to use '\\' instead of '\'.

Comment: what version of pandas do you use?

Comment: I added my test program with your sample data along with the output - everything works find (python 3.7.3 / pandas 0.25.0)

Comment: don't change anything at `'\s+'` - it is correct with one backslash.